# Strings returned from C++ code are padded with random values

Tags: python, c++, cython

I tried to write a Cython wrapper for some C++ code. When I compile and execute the C++ file, the input string gets translated correctly. Example output:

```
T*GRSLR*L
RKVDLCDSL
[...]
```

However when I run my code from the Cython wrapper in Python, the string is padded like this:

```
b'T*GRSLR*R\x8f\x96\x01'
b'RKVDLCDSR\x8f\x96\x01'
[...]
```

Sometimes this happens only with one sequence, sometimes with all of them.

I used the following Cython code to interface with my C++ code:

```
# file: sixframe.pyx
from libcpp.string cimport string
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef extern from "six_frame.cpp":
    cdef void initCodonTable()
    cdef vector[string] sixFrame(string seq)

def six_frame(bytes seq):
    return sixFrame(seq)

initCodonTable()
```

and the signature of my C++ function is:

```
// file: six_frame.cpp
vector<string> sixFrame(string seq){
    ...
}
```

This error terribly looks like I am using a wrong type and the end of the string is not detected correctly. I suspect the error is in the Cython code, since the C++ executable works as intended. Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: A [mcve] might be useful